# How to cancel photo upload?

Tags: 8.0, onedrive, photos, uploading

I accidentally chose all photos in my phone and told my phone to upload them to OneDrive. Actually I wanted to upload only a few photos because the others are already uploaded, so I tried to cancel the upload.

For the photo that is currently being uploaded, I can tap it and my phone will ask whether I want to cancel the upload. But for the photos that are in the queue to be uploaded, if I tap one of them, the option to cancel does not show.

I can wait until the upload finishes, but those are a lot of photos, and later I have to delete duplicates on OneDrive.

Any other way to cancel the upload?

Comment: I have the same problem. All photos have been selected and are qued to be uploaded to skydrive. I see no way to cancel the upload. It has not started yet as my wifi is off,,no way to uncheck all the photos/selections

Comment: The answer below was not what you were finding?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I really understand but:

In the Pictures Hub just below "Camera Roll, Albums, etc..." you can se a "upload(s) waiting" message.

Tap it and all pictures waiting for upload will show.

Long press an hit cancel. I think you can't do multiple actions here. Need to be one by one.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to settings in your phone
2. Swipe to left, under the applications, look for photos+camera
3. Scroll down and press then One Drive
4. Then choose the option of it (Don't Upload)